# Fetch News Data from right Scrollbar using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I am using the following webpage https://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE%3AF&ei=LvflU_itN8zbkgW0i4GABQ
to get the data  from the right hand side scroller.

I have attached the screen shot where there is a red arrow marking the segment.

[image]

I have used the following code:

```
def parse():
    mainPage = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE%3AF&ei=LvflU_itN8zbkgW0i4GABQ")
    lSoupPage = BeautifulSoup(mainPage)

    for index in lSoupPage.findAll("div", {"class" : "jfk-scrollbar"}):
        for item in index.findAll("div", {"class" : "news-item"}):
            print item.a.text.strip()
```

I am not able to fetch the news-url by doing this. Please help.

Comment: That data is loaded via AJAX, you won't find it in the page source you loaded.

Comment: https://www.google.com/finance/kd?output=json&keydevs=1&recnews=0&cid=13606&ei=DPXpU9DhOIuUwQONpICoAw contains the data for that sidebar.

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters: how did you get this link?

Comment: By looking at the network tab in the Chrome developer tools, filtered on XHR (AJAX) requests, then seeing which one might contain the data. The data is not valid JSON, BTW, you'll need to use a EcmaScript-tolerant parser instead of the `json` module or use a regex to 'repair' the quoting of the keys in that response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sidebar is loaded over AJAX and is not part of the page itself.

The page has a content id:

```
cid = lSoupPage.find('link', rel='canonical')['href'].rpartition('=')[-1]
```

use this to get the news data:

```
newsdata = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.google.com/finance/kd?output=json&keydevs=1&recnews=0&cid=' + cid)
```

Unfortunately, the data returned is not valid JSON; the keys are not using quotes. It is valid ECMAScript, just not valid JSON.

You can either 'repair' this by using a regular expression, or use a lenient parser that accepts ECMAscript object notation.

The latter can be done with the external [`demjson` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/demjson):

```
>>> import demjson
>>> r = requests.get(
>>> data = demjson.decode(r.content)
>>> data.keys()
[u'clusters', u'result_total_articles', u'results_per_page', u'result_end_num', u'result_start_num']
>>> data['clusters'][0]['a'][0]['t']
u'Former Ford Motor Co. CEO joins Google board'
```

Repairing with a regular expression:

```
import re
import json

repaired_data = re.sub(r'(?<={|,)\s*(\w+)(?=:)', r'"\1"', broken_data)
data = json.loads(repaired_data)
```